# fabric password

Tags: python, fabric

Every time fabric runs, it asks for root password, can it be sent along same for automated proposes.

```
fab staging test
```

Comment: I would consider very carefully before adopting **any** strategy that involved storing passwords in plaintext - as environment vars, saved in scripts, even entered at the command line - much as I hate to contradict a luminary like A.M. (really, man, you've given me a **lot** of information over the years) - it lives in your command history and presents a security risk.

Comment: gomad, you are absolutely right regarding the dangers of plaintext passwords. The keychain module helps to store passwords securely, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964682/258772 how to use it with Fabric 2.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`fab -h` will show you all the options, you can also read them [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/fab.html#command-line-options).

In particular, and I quote,

> -p PASSWORD, --password=PASSWORD
>
> Sets env.password to the given string;
>   it will then be used as the default
>   password when making SSH connections
>   or calling the sudo program.

Answer (score 61):

I know you've asked about password but wouldn't it better to configure the system so that you can doing fabric (i.e. SSH) without password?

For this, on local machine do:

1. `ssh-keygen` and agree with all defaults (if you have no reasons do otherwise)
2. `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and copy that key

On remote machine:

1. `mkdir ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh`
2. `touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2 && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2`
3. Paste copied key into `authorized_keys2`

From now your remote machine “trusts” your local machine and allows logging it in without password. Handy.

Comment: use ssh-copy-id may be faster:
``ssh-copy-id``  
Usage: /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id [-i [identity_file]] [user@]machine

Answer (score 51):

You can also set passwords on a per host basis.
It wasn't obvious to me, so here it goes for anyone looking for this:

```
from fabric import env
env.hosts = ['user1@host1:port1', 'user2@host2.port2']
env.passwords = {'user1@host1:port1': 'password1', 'user2@host2.port2': 'password2'}
```

Fabric caches used passwords in the env.passwords dictionary.
It sets this cache using the full hosts string as key of that dictionary and the password as the value.
If you set this dictionary yourself before executing any task, Fabric won't ask for them at all.

Comment: Note - you must include port 22 even if you didn't specify it in ``env.hosts``. Got me

Answer (score 21):

It's also possible to set ssh password in `connect_args`

```
    conn = Connection(
    "{username}@{ip}:{port}".format(
        username=username,
        ip=ip,
        port=port,
    ),
    connect_kwargs={"password": password},
)
```

Comment: Thanks. The `connect_kwargs.password` notation in the docs was confusing me.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add for anyone who winds up here from a search, you can specify the `-I` option when running fab for it to prompt you for a default password to use. This way it won't be visible in your command history

example:

```
$ fab -I my_task
Initial value for env.password:
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this without putting the password in the process list (commands show up in ps aux) is to put it in the fabfile.py like so:

```
from fabric.context_managers import env
env.password = 'PASSWORD'
```

Put that before anything that goes to the remote system and it won't ask for a password anymore.

Comment: Just a note, this generates an error in the latest Fabric 1.5.3 and Paramiko 1.9.0.

Comment: Just remove the `from fabric import env`

Comment: New package is context_managers, `from fabric.context_managers import env`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to store the password securely in the operating system keyring service with the [keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) module, the password can then be automatically retrieved and used in `fabfile.py`.

You first need to store the password in the keyring, for example using the Python shell:

```
>>> import keyring
>>> keyring.set_password('some-host', 'some-user', 'passwd')
```

Then you can use it in `fabfile.py`, for example with Fabric 2:

```
from fabric import task
import keyring

@task
def restart_apache(connection):
    connection.config.sudo.password = keyring.get_password(connection.host, 'some-user')
    connection.sudo('service apache2 restart')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a default password into a `Connection` or `Group` using `connect_kwargs`. For example:

```
group = ThreadingGroup(*servers, connect_kwargs={
  'password': getpass('SSH password: '),
})
group.run(command)
```