# Fabric auto-login in Windows

Tags: python, windows, ssh, fabric, paramiko

Relevant question:

- [fabric password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339735/fabric-password)

I configured Putty to login with private-public keys (no password) using this guide:
http://www.codelathe.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/20/ssh-without-password-using-putty/

It works.

Now I want to run Fabric with no password prompt. This does not work and I get prompted for a password. I'm assuming Paramiko (or some other Fabric dependency) does not find the ppk file. Where do I place the private key file and how do I tell fabric / paramiko about it?

Running on Vista, using Python 2.6.5 and latest Fabric (0.91) / Putty (0.60).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding the following to your `fabfile.py` should work:

```
env.user = "your_username"
env.key_filename = ["/path/to/keyfile"]
```

See the [fabric docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/usage/env.html#key-filename).

Comment: looks great but doesn't work. I still get prompted for the password!

Comment: Resolved! I had to export the key to the OpenSSH format in puttygen for it to work. This, with your pointer resolved the issue. Thanks! +1.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help.  Totally forgot about that OpenSSH export step (It's been a while since I used windows + putty).