# Can I prevent fabric from prompting me for a sudo password?

Tags: python, sudo, fabric

I am using [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.2/) to run commands on a remote server. The user with which I connect on that server has some sudo privileges, and does not require a password to use these privileges. When SSH'ing into the server, I can run `sudo blah` and the command executes without prompting for a password. When I try to run the same command via Fabric's `sudo` function, I get prompted for a password. This is because Fabric builds a command in the following manner when using `sudo`:

```
sudo -S -p <sudo_prompt> /bin/bash -l -c "<command>"
```

Obviously, my user does not have permission to execute `/bin/bash` without a password.

I've worked around the problem by using `run("sudo blah")` instead of `sudo("blah")`, but I wondered if there is a better solution. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try passing `shell=False` to sudo.  That way /bin/bash won't be added to the sudo command.  `sudo('some_command', shell=False)`

From line 503 of [fabric/operations.py](http://code.fabfile.org/repositories/entry/fabric/0.9/fabric/operations.py#L503):

```
if (not env.use_shell) or (not shell):
    real_command = "%s %s" % (sudo_prefix, _shell_escape(command))
```

the else block looks like this:

```
                                             # V-- here's where /bin/bash is added
real_command = '%s %s "%s"' % (sudo_prefix, env.shell,
    _shell_escape(cwd + command))
```

Comment: I do have SSH keys set up. The issue is with the way Fabric passes the command off to sudo, not with SSH.

Comment: I see, so what's wrong with just defining the second function?  Why complicate things?

Comment: As I noted, I've basically already done that. I just wondered if there was a config option or something that I'm missing.

Comment: Hrm, thought I had tried that and it didn't work, but I gave it a shot just now and it did.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. One note that was screwing me up: I had this command inside a with block (for my virtualenv) and it was not working (which is probably what user802596 is complaining about). Moving it out of there solved the problem.

Comment: I did not follow the solution. Do we need to change somethings in fabric/operations.py?

Comment: I did not follow the solution. Do we need to modify fabric/operations.py ?

Answer (score 13):

You can use:

```
from fabric.api import env
# [...]
env.password = 'yourpassword'
```

Comment: This was the alternative I wanted :)

Comment: I can see "yourpassword" there... :-o

Comment: Has this been deprecated? I'm getting an error:     `from fabric.api import env
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fabric.api'`         The `fabric` version I have is `2.6.0` Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

In your /etc/sudoers file add

```
user ALL=NOPASSWD: some_command
```

where user is your sudo user and some_command the command you want to run with fabric, then on the fabric script run sudo it with shell=False:

```
sudo('some_command', shell=False)
```

this works for me

Comment: This is a security flaw

Answer (score 1):

Linux noob here but I found this question while trying to install graphite-fabric onto an EC2 AMI. Fabric kept prompting for a root password.

The evntual trick was to pass in the ssh private key file to fabric.

```
fab -i key.pem graphite_install -H root@servername
```

Comment: Can you provide a full code example? I'm also running into this issue and your answer seems to be the solution I need. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry - that's all I have. I was actually getting graphite installed - full notes here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436606/using-etsys-statsd-in-a-windows-environment/10892374#10892374

Comment: The password prompt you faced was the login prompt, not the password prompt for sudo. For your problem, key-based authentication is the correct answer. 

But for others who find this via Google, it's important to KNOW what is prompting you for a password - in order to solve it. 

Prompts can originate from 3 places: login, the remote sudo prompt, or even from fabric itself (ie if you call a function with sudo() then Fabric will try the authentication it knows about else it will send you a prompt... even if the remote system did not ask for a prompt).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use passwords for multiple machines:

```
from fabric import env
env.hosts = ['user1@host1:port1', 'user2@host2.port2']
env.passwords = {'user1@host1:port1': 'password1', 'user2@host2.port2': 'password2'}
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5568219/552671

Answer (score 0):

In your `/etc/sudoers` file, you could add

```
user ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/bash
```

...where `user` is your Fabric username.

Obviously, you can only do this if you have root access, as `/etc/sudoers` is only writable by root.

Also obviously, this isn't terribly secure, as being able to execute `/bin/bash` leaves you open to essentially anything, so if you don't have root access and have to ask a sysadmin to do this for you, they probably won't.

Comment: Right, I don't want the user to be able to do `/bin/bash` without a password.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this same issue, and found Crossfit_and_Beer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080546/3926181) confusing.

A supported way to achieve this is via using `env.sudo_prefix`, as documented by [this github commit](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/commit/6bf1d905267917208200c9999ffeb995357dbd6c) (from [this PR](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/pull/609))

My example of use:

```
env.sudo_prefix = 'sudo '
```