# Python Fabric and Amazon EC2 : Sudo password asked

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, fabric

You know that on EC2, there is no password associated with "ubuntu" user. With the following lines, if I try to run :

fab development install_dir

I get :

[ec2-46-51-132-252.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] sudo: chown -R webadmin:webadmin /var/www
[ec2-46-51-132-252.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] Login password:

I tried to add shell=False to sudo method (according to [Can I prevent fabric from prompting me for a sudo password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737003/can-i-prevent-fabric-from-prompting-me-for-a-sudo-password)), but it doesn't change anything

Any idea ? Thanks a lot !

```
def development():
    env.envname = 'development'
    env.user = 'ubuntu'
    env.group = 'ubuntu'
    env.chuser = 'webadmin'
    env.chgroup = 'webadmin'
    env.hosts = ['ec2-***.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com']
    env.envname_abriev = 'dev'
    env.key_filename = '/home/xx/.ssh/xx.pem'

    env.postgresql_version = '9.0'

def install_dir():
    if not exists('/var/www'):
        sudo('mkdir /var/www')
    sudo('chown -R %s:%s /var/www' % (env.chuser, env.chgroup))
```

Comment: What does it do if you just use `run` like this: `run('sudo chown -R ...')`?

Comment: i get this with a regular run() as well, not just sudo().  Setting shell and pty to False does not help at all.

Comment: turns out my issue was i had since changed my pem file key and not updated the fabfile!  all good now.

Comment: I have this same problem. Very frustrating. I can manually login to the shell and sudo without a password, but for some reason Fabric cannot.

Answer (score 4):

Download (or create) a keypair file from aws as shown below[image: Download keypair from the highlighted section]

Create a file called fabfile.py
and set its contents as follows:

```
from fabric.context_managers import cd
from fabric.operations import sudo
from fabric.api import run, env
import os

HOME = os.getenv('HOME')

env.user = 'ubuntu'
env.hosts = ['PUBLICDNS.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com','ANOTHERSERVER.compute.amazonaws.com'] #can add multiple instances
env.key_filename = [
'%s/<your-keypair-file>.pem'%HOME
     ] #assuming keypair file is located in HOME

#example code we want to run on remote machine
def update():
    with cd('/var/www'):
            sudo('svn update')
                 with cd ('/var/www/cache'):
                       run('rm -rf *')
    sudo('service lighttpd restart')
```

To run the file, type fab update in the terminal.

Comment: What does this have to do with the OP's question? He can login to the server, so he already has his key pair. But he's getting asked for a password when he runs sudo, which won't be solved by generating a new key pair...

Comment: Cerin - OP seems to have embedded everything in the development() function. This function is not being called by default when fabric install_dir is executed on the shell. I reckon while answering the question, I did not pay attention towards the development() function. I wrote what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify keypair file name associated with your EC2 instance while running fab command.

Usage: `fab [options] <command>[:arg1,arg2=val2,host=foo,hosts='h1;h2',...] ...`

Options:

```
-R ROLES, --roles=ROLES
                    comma-separated list of roles to operate on

-i KEY_FILENAME       path to SSH private key file. May be repeated.
```

Comment: OP is talking about the sudo password, not the ssh password.