# Call /etc/sudoers commands from fabric

Tags: python, fabric, sudoers

In my `/etc/sudoers` I have:

```
# Allow the picky user to restart its own gunicorn process
picky ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/supervisorctl restart picky
```

I can indeed run this command from the picky user:

```
$ su picky
$ sudo supervisorctl restart picky
```

In my fabfile.py I have the following:

```
from fabric.api import sudo

def restart():
    sudo("supervisorctl restart picky")
```

However, when I run my fabric file, it still prompts for a password:

```
[picky@myhost] sudo: supervisorctl restart picky
[picky@myhost] out: sudo password:
```

How can I run sudo commands inside Fabric such that I don't need to provide a password?

*Edit*:

I've noticed this works:

```
from fabric.api import run

def restart():
    run("sudo supervisorctl restart picky")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737003/can-i-prevent-fabric-from-prompting-me-for-a-sudo-password, when you use the fabric `sudo` command that command is sent to a shell. The real command that is executed contains a call to `/bin/bash` in it, which is why it doesn't match with your sudoer entry.

To get around that, simply add `shell=False` to your call:

```
from fabric.api import sudo

def restart():
    sudo("supervisorctl restart picky", shell=False)
```

You might have to add the full path to `supervisorctl`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Adding the full path to `supervisorctl` was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Two items I noticed; your syntax might be incorrect and you might have rules that override this one later in the file.

I'd change your `picky` entry to `picky  ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL`, place it at the END of the file (or at least after other entries similar to `root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`) and see if it works. If so, then change it to `picky  ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/supervisorctl restart picky` and see if that works. It should.

Comment: This is the last rule in the file. Changing the rule to `picky ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` makes the fabric script work, but of course doesn't limit the commands. Changing the rule to `picky ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/supervisorctl restart picky` doesn't change the behaviour.