# Fabric is asking for password at the prompt even though password is specified in code

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I'm running a small code that uses fabric's `rsync_project` function to connect to a remote machine and transfer a file to it. I've assigned `env.password` with the password of the server.

However, when I run the code, I get prompted for password. After entering the password, the file gets transferred. But I do not want to get prompted.

Here's my code:

```
from fabric import environment
from fabric.contrib.project import rsync_project
env.hosts = ['172.16.154.134']
env.password = 'user@123'
def sync(remote_dir, local_dir):
    rsync_project(remote_dir, local_dir)
```

Maybe I have misunderstood what `env.password` is for. If so, please tell me some other way to get rid of the prompt that asks for password.

Thanks

Comment: Relevant github issue: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/817

Comment: @Sinkingpoint The link throws a 404. It's not working.

Comment: have a look at this so question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737003/5476782

Comment: @Karlos This link provides my question as the answer. The point is, even after setting env.password, I'm being prompted for a password.

Comment: the first answer tells you to use shell=False, did you try that?

Comment: @Karlos By configuring if you mean generating a key pair, I can do that. But I don't want to do that. Reason is that I'll connect to multiple systems and putting the public key file on each one of them will not be possible.

Comment: then in fabric you can try `env.passwords` as it says [here](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/976) and check fabric docs for **the version of fabric** you use

Comment: @Karlos Downgraded fabric to 1.6.0. Tried with both env.password and env.passwords. Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misunderstanding.  Once you set env in code, whatever function you call should be called with `execute`.

```
from fabric.state import env
from fabric.decorators import task
from fabric.api import execute
from fabric.contrib.project import rsync_project

env.hosts = ['172.16.154.134']
env.password = 'user@123'

def internal_sync(remote_dir, local_dir):
    rsync_project(remote_dir, local_dir)

# use task to define the external endpoint for the fab command line
@task
def sync(remote_dir, local_dir):
    """Does an rsync from remote_dir => local_dir"""
    # above docstring for `fab --list`
    # call `internal_sync` using the env
    # parameters we set in code
    execute(internal_sync, remote_dir, local_dir)
```

And from the command line:

```
fab sync:/path/to/remote,/path/to/local
```