# Fabric 3 ask sudo password once

Tags: python, fabric

I am using fabric to automate some deployment stuff. Below is a sample of the code I used:

```
run(f"sudo -H -u www-data bash -c 'rm -r project_name' ")
run(f"sudo -H -u www-data bash -c '/opt/www-data/project-name/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt' ")

run("sudo systemctl stop gunicorn")
run("sudo systemctl start gunicorn")
```

Everytime each line of code was ran, the terminal ask for my user password, is there a way I can enter the password just once?

Edit:
I am using python3 and the essence of the script was to run the commands on a different user, rather than my own.

Update:

I achieved this by running fabric with "-I" param.

```
fabric -I deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

Every `run()` invocation is a separate shell, as would be a `sudo()` invocation. The `sudo` credentials are per shell, so they are gone every time.

A quick and dirty way would be to lump all commands into one sudo invocation.

A nicer way would be to have a [`sudoers` file](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.23/sudoers.man.html) on the target host(s) and give each user the required privileges to run particular commands without entering a password.

Comment: This is what I am thinking but this would be my final resort. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `run` is not the ideal way to achieve this.

[`fabric.operations.sudo(*args, **kwargs)`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.sudo) is something that can be used to achieve what you are attempting.
Please be careful with `sudo` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fab script like below and then iterate over the host list you want to run the commands because you can passwd username and password in the script itself so to avoid password invocation:

```
# testCheck.py
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import sys
from fabric.api import *
env.skip_bad_hosts=True
env.command_timeout=160
env.user = 'user_name'
env.shell = "/bin/sh -c"
env.warn_only = True
env.password = 'user_password'
def readhost():
    env.hosts = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin.readlines()]

def hosts():
  with settings(warn_only=True):

      output=sudo("ls -l /myfolder",shell=False)


# cat hostfile.txt| | /usr/local/bin/fab readhost -f testCheck.py hosts -P -z 5

OR supplying password at command line
# cat hostfile.txt | /usr/local/bin/fab readhost -f testCheck.py --password=your_pass hosts -P -z 5


--> argument "-P" refers to  parallel execution method
--> argument "-z" refres to the number of concurrent processes to use in parallel mode
```

exapmle hostfile.txt:

```
server1
server2
server3
server4
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: this is for python2.7, I am using fabric 3 since I use python 3.

Comment: @BatutoyTria, it will run in python3 as well just change that.

Comment: i don't have sudoer on individual clients and using ldap account as a sudo it helps me..  there me be different ways and security constraints though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ssh keys, then set the fabric environment variable `key_filename`:

```
env.key_filename='/path/to/key.pem'

# set the following as well
env.user='username'
env.host='hostaddr'
```

It will ask you for the password only one time.
Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737003/5476782) question regarding avoid to enter any sudo password when using fabric.