# How do I run a Fabric arbitrary sudo command without having to type password?

Tags: python, fabric

With Fabric, according to [this documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/usage/fab.html#arbitrary-remote-shell-commands), you can run an arbitrary shell command without having a `fabfile` like this:

```
fab -H host1,host2 -- echo 'hello, world!'
```

You can also run `sudo` commands in the same way, but you will be prompted for the `sudo` password for every host in the list.

Is there a way to avoid having to type the `sudo` password for each host, must like the Fabric function `sudo()` works?

Comment: Original poster seems to be asking how can I do the following without being prompted for the sudo password for each host:  `fab -H host0,host1,host2 -- sudo /root/bin/my_script_that_must_be_run_as_root.sh`.  I know how to write a fabfile to do it, but I'd like to know how to do it as an add-hoc command, too.  The -I option doesn't seem to work in this case.  I am testing with Fabric 1.6.0.

Answer (score 3):

just add the following line to etc/sudoers where myusername should be the intended user who will run sudo. You should understand the security implications of doing the following. You also might want to restrict the options below to limit the commands that the user can sudo without a password.

```
myusername    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `env.password` to let fabric do the magic or...

...you can also use passwords for multiple machines:

```
from fabric import env
env.hosts = ['user1@host1:port1', 'user2@host2.port2']
env.passwords = {'user1@host1:port1': 'password1', 'user2@host2.port2': 'password2'}
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5568219/552671

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider a pam-authentication against a ssh key-file. A nice primer would be this blog-[entry](http://www.drhevans.com/blog/posts/195-using-ssh-agent-for-sudo-authentication/).
This way you wouldn't have to compromise security. You could even copy the keyfile prior to sudo-operations into your remote-account assuming you do have a qualified account. :-)