# Python Fabric Laibrary ssh connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, fabric

I am unable to understand how should I set username, password, ip and port for my remote host in python fabric. I followed [this](http://advanced-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fabric.html). But the docs only explains like below:

```
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.api import env

env.hosts = [
    'newyork',
    'seattle',
    'localhost',
    ]

def host_type():
    run('uname -s')

def diskspace():
    run('df')
```

I wonder how they are connecting to the hosts network etc without giving any connection or credential information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked:
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/fab.html

You should use as a rule of thumb in SSH, SSH keys not password.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5568219/1152669

```
from fabric import env
env.hosts = ['user1@host1:port1', 'user2@host2.port2']
env.passwords = {'user1@host1:port1': 'password1', 'user2@host2.port2': 'password2'}
```

Comment: Why e.v.hosts and env.passwords are separate? Can't I write like, env.hosts = {'user1@host1:port1': 'password1', 'user2@host2.port2': 'password2'}

Comment: I tried you suggestion this way, env.hosts = [username+'@'+host+':'+port]
env.passwords = {username+'@'+host+':'+port: password}, but it is giving me a syntax error at colon

Comment: sorry my mistake. I was using square brackets instead of curly while setting up env.passwords